# Эффект поднятия текста

Tags: html, css

Как добавить эффект поднятия текста при наведении на него курсора?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На чистом CSS это будет выглядеть так.

```css
.fly-on-hover span{
    display: inline-block;
}

.fly-on-hover:hover span{
    // Для более плавного эффекта, если не нужно — можно удалить.
    transition: transform 300ms;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="fly-on-hover">
    <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант через позиционирование:

```css
.container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
}

.text:hover {
  top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="text">Текст</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @entithat Странно, проверила сейчас в файрфоксе и хроме - вроде, ведет себя прилично)

Comment: Попробуйте чуть ниже самого текста навести, забавно:)

Comment: @entithat Да, точно, теперь поймала) Спасибо!

Comment: @maridu, Я не случайно проверяю hover на родительский блок а не на сам текст. Увеличьте высоту позиционирования и увидите что текст начнет прыгать) К тому же свойство top вызывает перерисовывание layout, этот способ стоит применять только для устаревших браузеров.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin Спасибо, буду иметь в виду!